# Retain certain builds and release indefinitely

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

We are using Azure DevOps services and I want to know how to configure certain builds and releases to be retained indefinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the builds list click on the `...` and **Retain**:

[image]

In the releases list click in the `...` and **Retain indefinitely**:

[image]

Comment: Retain the builds retains it indefinitely?

Comment: @Chubsdad Yes :)